# Where does MongoDB for PCF Development Services store all data values?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

My current application is using MongoDb running on localhost with default port 27017. My web application reflect the data that is stored in the database. When I push this application to cloud foundry, and bind the MONGO service, it uses another database. Where and how can I view/access all the data that are being inputted. On the local machine I am able to use db.collection.find() and it queries all of my data.

Comment: You could push a management app into CF (see e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) and bind the service to that too, but the database is deliberately inaccessible from outside.

Comment: So, it is impossible to manually enter values? eg; local machine we can do db.collection.insert ({ })

Comment: I can't think of a way to answer that without repeating myself, so: see above.

Comment: You posted a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349499. I have answered that question. I would recommend continuing the discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored in the CF Mongo service. You can check where it is running by inspecting the values in VCAP_SERVICES section of your application environment:

```
cf env <app name>
```

In the environment you can see the connection details, but the DB should not be accessible directly. To connect to the DB you can use a tunnel similar to Chisel or Crowbar.

There is a Chisel [fork](https://github.com/morikat/chisel) that also contains [instructions](https://github.com/morikat/chisel#how-to-connect-cloud-foundry-v2-service) on how to connect to CF services.

Comment: If your CF provider is running Diego, you don't need to do this.  You can simply use `cf ssh` and run a cli based client from inside your container.  I haven't tried this but you might even be able to use something like sshuttle to tunnel a client from your local machine to connect to the service with a GUI client.  https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle

Comment: Actually you don't need `sshuttle`.  You can just use an SSH tunnel.  Bind a service to an app, run `cf env` to get the host, port and creds (or make a service key). Then run `cf ssh -N -L <localport>:<service-fqdn-or-ip>:<remote-port> app-name` (the app you connect to doesn't strictly matter, it's just the one we are tunneling through). Now connect a client to `localhost:<localport>` and use the creds you got from `cf env`.

Comment: cf ssh is the simplest way provided your network supports it. If your only option is HTTP/HTTPS access you're stuck with a tunnel.

I think Daniel's answer is the correct way to do it though.